# Could not load file or Assembly `System.Windows.Forms , Version=4.0.0.0` cannot find the file

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, types, .net-assembly

I am using reflection to search through assemblies that contain a certain interface, the one i am trying to find is a windows form that implements that interface, however the error i am getting claiming it cannot load the file, could it be down to not using reflection correctly or loading in the file properly.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "*.dll");

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    Assembly da = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

                    foreach (Type type in da.GetTypes())
                    {
                        debugger = (IDebugger)Activator.CreateInstance(type.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDebugger)));
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", file, e.ToString());
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (!(debugger == null))
                debugger.VirtualMachine = this;
```

Error

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at SVM.SvmVirtualMachine..ctor() in C:\Users\Ollie\Desktop\Work\SimpleVM\SVM\VirtualMachine\VirtualMachine\SvmVirtualMachine.cs:line 49
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Value of the File

```
C:\Users\Ollie\Desktop\Work\SimpleVM\SVM\bin\Debug\Debugger.dll: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
```

Help from Lecturer - Fix (Only Fix available atm i believe)

```
- In the .csproj file 
- Change <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> change this to <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop"> 
- the <PropertyGroup> element with OutputType and TargetFramework nested inside it. Add a nested child before the </PropertyGroup> tag: <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
- Save and Rebuild
```

Comment: Can you show the actual value of your variable `file` and not only the error message?

Comment: You'll also load the base type of a type, so it can easily refer to, say, the Control class in System.Windows.Forms.dll.  Not finding it is unhealthy, it is stored in the GAC.  But will bomb if you target .NET 3.5 or less or if you target .NETCore.  This is not the right way to implement a plugin architecture.

Comment: If you're running this code under .NET Core, you should also [understand AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext).  Calling Assembly.LoadFrom may not behave the way you expect in .NET Core (if you're familiar with how it works in .NET Framework).